# Hiding Android app in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an application in **playstore**.

**My requirement is to:**

1. Show this app to users with API level 22 in playstore.
2. Hide the app from user who is having device with API 23.

Basically i want to hide my app from Android M users since we are not supporting it. From the Android developer site I found that `android:maxSdkVersion` can help for this. But its an deprecated method. I need an alternative solution.

Comment: `maxSdkVersion` is not deprecated it is just _"not recommended"_.

Comment: After 2.1 maxSdkVersion is ignored, since Android's latest versions are always backward compatible.

Comment: When you set the `targetSdkVersion 22` and `compileSdkVersion 22`, it may hide from play store.